# Get Concrete Implementation of Interface with Generic Parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface, abstraction

I'm feeling pretty dumb right now.  Not sure why I can't solve this.  I have a repository interface:

```
public interface ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<T> where T : CollateralItemBase
{
    int Add(T collateralItem);
    T Get(int collateralID);
}
```

and many implementations, each implementing one of the 10 models that inherit from `CollateralItemBase`.  For example:

```
internal sealed class CollateralItemCertifiedDepositRepository : ServiceBaseRepository, ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit>
{
   int Add(CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit collateralItem) { /*...*/ }
   CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit Get(int collateralID)  { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now i just need to switch on the incoming `CollateralItemBase` type to get the repository I need:

```
private ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<???> GetRepository(CollateralItemBase item) 
{
    switch (item.GetType().Name)
    {
            case "CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit": return new CollateralItemCertifiedDepositRepository();
            //...
    }
```

I just need to figure out what to return from this method, for other methods to act on whichever repository I return.  How do I refactor this to get it working?
  I'm pretty sure I have a covariance/contravariance problem.  Again, I'm feeling pretty dumb, just drawing a blank.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `GetRepository` be a generic method so that you can pass the type as a parameter, rather than passing an object that you don't access apart from checking the type via reflection?

Comment: it could potentially.  But in my app (wpf), I never actually need to manipulate the real type myself.  I use a template selector to get the right template for the actual type, and the binding 'magically' works without me casting.  So in all of my ViewModels, I'm working with a `CollateralItemBase` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in two stages. Add a non-generic base interface to `ICollateralItemBaseImplementation` then cast to the generic version.

```
public interface ICollateralItemBaseImplementation
{
}

public interface ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<T> : ICollateralItemBaseImplementation
    where T : CollateralItemBase
{
    int Add(T collateralItem);
    T Get(int collateralID);
}

public static class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<T> GetRepository<T>(T item)
        where T : CollateralItemBase
    {
        return (ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<T>)GetRepositoryImpl(item);
    }

    private static ICollateralItemBaseImplementation GetRepositoryImpl<T>(T item)
            where T : CollateralItemBase
    {
        switch (item.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit":
                return new CollateralItemCertifiedDepositRepository();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

internal static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var repo = RepositoryFactory.GetRepository(new CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit());
        Debug.Assert(repo is CollateralItemCertifiedDepositRepository);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Colin.  I figured I'd have to have a non-generic interface somehow to get the types working.  This fixed it for me

Answer (score -1):

what about a generic return param of base type

```
private ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<T>     GetRepository(CollateralItemBase item)  where T : ServiceBaseRepository
{
switch (item.GetType().Name)
{
        case "CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit": return new CollateralItemCertifiedDepositRepository();
        //...
}
```

Comment: That won't compile. 
First `T` should be of type `CollateralItemBase`
Second, `CollateralItemCertifiedDepositRepository` does not implement `ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<T>`, it only implements `ICollateralItemBaseImplementation<CollateralItemCertifiedDeposit >` so you'll get an error when you try to return it.